# Correlation between the CDFs of two normal correlated variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Assume that $X\sim N(0,\sigma_x^2)$, $Y\sim N(0,\sigma_y^2)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are correlated with a coefficient $\rho$. Can we solve analytically for  $corr( \Phi_x(X),\Phi_y(Y))$, where $\Phi$ stands for the CDF?

Comment: What is $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$?

Comment: I have used $P$ instead of the CDF $\Phi$.

Comment: $\Phi(X)$ follows Uniform$(0,1)$ (this might help!)